# Redux Persist + Redux toolkit $CombinedState error

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I'm trying to add redux persist to redux toolkit but for some reason I get an `Exported variable 'store' has or is using name '$CombinedState' from external module ".../node_modules/redux/index" but cannot be named.` error on vscode.

This is my store configuration file with the added persist config, which if I remove, works fine.

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import { createEpicMiddleware } from "redux-observable";
import rootEpic from "onsite/redux/rootEpic";
import rootReducer from "onsite/redux/rootReducer";

const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware();

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage: storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

// Line that shows error
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: [epicMiddleware],
});

export default store;

epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic);
```

Other things I have tried are putting the `combineReducers` declaration (from `rootReducer`import) into the same file or converting the file into plain javascript, with same or similar results. For some reason typescript decides to still haunt me on a javascript file :)

The code still runs, so I'm tempted to leave it like that, but I would like to get rid of it.

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? I have a monorepo and updated all react-scripts deps from 3 to 4 and getting this error everywhere my tsconfig has `declaration: true` on it

Comment: Left the error since the code still runs haha

Comment: I have the same issue, also have `declaration: true` but i sort of need it, and my code does not run, any suggestions or work arounds?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and here's what I figured out:

You need to include `Store` from redux, and use it as your type definition for your own `store` return value. Short answer:

```
import { Store } from 'redux';
[...]
const store:Store = configureStore([...])
[...]
export default store;
```

Longer answer:

As I understand it, what was happening is that `Store` type uses `$CombinedState` as part of its definition. When `configureStore()` returns, it inherits the `State` type. However since `State` is not explicitly used in your code, that now means that your code includes a value that references `$CombinedState`, despite it not existing anywhere in your code either. When you then try to export it out of your module, you're exporting a value with a type that doesn't exist within your module, and so you get an error.

You can import `State` from redux (which will in turn explicity cause your code to bring in `$CombinedState`), then use it to explicitly define `store` that gets assigned the return of `configureStore()`. You should then no longer be exporting unknown named types.

You can also be more specific with your `Store` type, as it is a generic:

```
const store:Store<RootState>
```

Although I'm not entirely sure if that would be a circular dependency, since your RootState depends on store.

Comment: Generally, you should never annotate your `store` variable with any type. That store you get from `configureStore` has a very complex type, containing all the information about the different reducers and middlewares your store is configured with - `store.dispatch` will have different behaviour based on those middleware and that type is as a result going to be used to [derive further types from it](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript#define-root-state-and-dispatch-types). Any manual annotation will erase all that info.

Answer (score -2):

Adding a

```
import { $CombinedState } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
```

in that file should usually resolve that error.