# Exported variable 'store' has or is using name '$CombinedState' from external module error Redux toolkit and redux persist

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

Hi I'm trying to get redux persist working with redux toolkit (also in typescript)
I'm getting the following error:

`Exported variable 'store' has or is using name '$CombinedState' from external module  "home/..../node_modules/redux/index" but cannot be named.`

I see this question is asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66483650/redux-persist-redux-toolkit-combinedstate-error), but it's not answered as well.

following is my code, please let me know if you have an idea on how to fix this, thanks

```js
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import myModuleReducer from "../../modules/my-module/redux/my-module-slice";
import myModuleTwoReducer from "../../modules/my-module-two/redux/my-module-two-slice";

import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage' // defaults to localStorage for web

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    myModule: myModuleReducer,
    myModuleTwo: myModuleTwoReducer,
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware({
    serializableCheck: {
      ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
    },
  }),
})

export default store;
export const persistor = persistStore(store)


export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

Comment: Have you tried Changing "strict" to false in `tsconfig.json`

Comment: hmm, tried it, didn't work, what works is if i set `declaration` to false it does build, but the problem is I need the declarations since this is a sub module, but that sort of works for now

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, and here's what I figured out:

You need to include `Store` from redux, and use it as your type definition for your own `store` return value. Short answer:

```
import {combineReducers, Store} from 'redux';
[...]
const store:Store = configureStore([...])
[...]
export default store;
```

Longer answer:

As I understand it, what was happening is that `Store` type uses `$CombinedState` as part of its definition. When `configureStore()` returns, it inherits the `State` type. However since `State` is not explicitly used in your code, that now means that your code includes a value that references `$CombinedState`, despite it not existing anywhere in your code either. When you then try to export it out of your module, you're exporting a value with a type that doesn't exist within your module, and so you get an error.

You can import `State` from redux (which will in turn explicity cause your code to bring in `$CombinedState`), then use it to explicitly define `store` that gets assigned the return of `configureStore()`. You should then no longer be exporting unknown named types.

You can also be more specific with your `Store` type, as it is a generic:

```
const store:Store<RootState>
```

Although I'm not entirely sure if that would be a circular dependency, since your RootState depends on store.

Answer (score 1):

A potential solution would be to extend the RootState type to include $CombinedState as follows:

```
import { $CombinedState } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState> & {
  readonly [$CombinedState]?: undefined;
};
```